# Passing parameter to ViewModel's overloaded constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, overloading, viewmodel

I've got a creator of a viewmodel in my controller, and I'm wondering - how do I simplify it? I was thinking of moving this code to my viewmodel and make an overloaded constructor that would populate it, but is it right to pass parameters to a viewmodel? As far as I know I should avoid passing parameters to a viewmodel. Or is it fine when we're talking about an overloaded constructor?

```
public CountryViewModel CreateViewModel(List<Country> countries)
    {
        CountryViewModel flags = new CountryViewModel();

        flags.Countries = countries;
        flags.CountriesCount = countries.Count;
        flags.EuropeanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Europe", countries);
        flags.AsianCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Asia", countries);
        flags.AfricanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Africa", countries);
        flags.SAmericanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("South America", countries);
        flags.NAmericanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("North America", countries);
        flags.AustralianCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Australia", countries);
        flags.CountriesArea = countryService.GetCountriesArea(countries).ToString("N0");
        flags.CountriesPercent = countryService.CountCountriesPercent(flags.CountriesCount);
        flags.CountriesAreaPercent = countryService.CountCountriesAreaPercent(countryService.GetCountriesArea(countries));
        flags.ShareLink = "?id=" + sharingService.GenerateGuid();

        return flags;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an extension method to do the model translate, let code be simplified instead of overloaded constructor.

```
public static class ViewModelExtension{

    public static CountryViewModel CreateViewModel(this List<Country> countries){

        var countryService = new CountryService();

        CountryViewModel flags = new CountryViewModel();
        flags.Countries = countries;
        flags.CountriesCount = countries.Count;
        flags.EuropeanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Europe", countries);
        flags.AsianCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Asia", countries);
        flags.AfricanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Africa", countries);
        flags.SAmericanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("South America", countries);
        flags.NAmericanCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("North America", countries);
        flags.AustralianCountriesCount = countryService.GetContinentCount("Australia", countries);
        flags.CountriesArea = countryService.GetCountriesArea(countries).ToString("N0");
        flags.CountriesPercent = countryService.CountCountriesPercent(flags.CountriesCount);
        flags.CountriesAreaPercent = countryService.CountCountriesAreaPercent(countryService.GetCountriesArea(countries));
        flags.ShareLink = "?id=" + sharingService.GenerateGuid();

        return flags;
    }
}
```

use like this in the controller.

```
var viewModel = countries.CreateViewModel();
```

Or I another way you can try to use [automapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) this framework is powerful for transfer data between class.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not putting this in the view-model. Your code is calling various services and cobbling together the results. This is orchestration logic and actually belongs either in the controller or in another service if possible.